# Xcode 5 - Scene Kit Tool Warning

Tags: xcode5, collada, scenekit

I have an XCode project for iPad that uses a third party framework (NinevehGL) for importing 3D Collada (.dae) files. This works fine for existing .dae already in the Copy Bundle Resources.

However, since upgrading to Xcode 5, when I add a new .dae file to the Resources, I get a warning:

**/scntool: Resource is left untouched because Scene Kit will not be able to load it on 10.6. To solve this issue you can change your product's Deployment Target to 10.9 or later.**

I am running this on iPad so not using Scene Kit.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this warning by going to the project's Build Phases, and then making sure .dae files are marked as "Uncompressed" under the Copy Bundle Resources section.

Comment: Thanks for your help but same warning persists whether set to Compressed or Uncompressed.

Comment: Seems to work if I add a Build Rule to process DAE files with; # scntool